# Prove the property of complex roots

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Prove that if $z_1$ is any $n$-root of $z$, that is, $z_1^n=z$, then, $z_1,z_1\omega, \dotsc, z_1\omega^{n-1}$ are the $n$-roots $n$-th of $z$ where $\omega = \cos(2\pi/n)+i\sin(2\pi/n)$.

Comment: Note:   $\omega^n=1$

Comment: Yes, but, how can I proceed to proof that? I can show what I've tried to do

Comment: Note:  $\omega=e^{2\pi i/n}$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\omega = e^{2\pi i/n}$, and $\omega^n=(e^{2\pi i/n})^n=e^{2\pi i}=\cos(2\pi)+i\sin(2\pi)=1$. If $z_1\omega^{n-1}$ is the n-root n-th of $z$ then $$(z_1\omega^{n-1})^n=z_1^n(\omega^{n-1})^n=z(\omega^n)^n(\omega^{-1})^n=z(1)^n(\omega^n)^{-1}=z$$

Comment: what about $z_1\omega^k$ where $0<k<n-1$?

Answer (score 0):

$$(z_1\omega^k)^n=z_1^n\omega^{kn}=z\left(\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}nkn\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}nkn\right)\right)=z.$$